# Facebook user id different on test app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook API to enable users to register using Facebook. I store their user ID to check whether a user has already registered using Facebook. I have a development environment, a staging environment and a production environment. The development environment and staging environment use a testversion of the actual Facebook App.

Now here's the problem. Even though Facebook says that test apps share the same app-scoped user ids, I get different ID's for the same person, thus disabling users that registered on one environment, to login on another.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can verify this behaviour in the case if you production app was created before the introduction of the Graph API v2.0, but created a test app thereafter.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/ states that

> Test Apps share the same app-scoped User ID namespace as your
>   production app making it simpler to debug issues with app-scoped IDs,
>   or in cases where you use a copy of your production database for
>   development.

I guess it's something else if the production app doesn't use Graph API >=v2.0. Maybe it would make sense to open a bug with Facebook to verify this behaviour.

Comment: Aye, I reported the bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/848026168550850). Seems it's a valid bug and they are investigating the issue.

Comment: As of right now, this is still an issue. My production app (the original) was created on v1 of the API. I just got around to setting up staging (set up on v2 of the API), and the app_scoped ids are indeed different, which is a giant pain in the ass considering that it's my only authentication at the moment.